# Need help on setting dates in my code

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to dynamically get dates i want to use in a where clause of an sql string.

Here is my try.

```
GregorianCalendar c1= new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar c= new GregorianCalendar();
// get date a year ago
c1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-11);                     
 Date myStartDate =c1.getTime();                        
Date myendDate = c.getTime();

String s = fm.format(myStartDate);

String e = fm.format(myendDate);

Log.e("sdate", s);
Log.e("edate", e);
```

This prints start date as 2010-02-18 and end date 2014-03-18.

And it is not consistent!...tried again and i got 2008-10-18!

How can pull it off?
Here is the date formatting.

```
SimpleDateFormat fm =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

What i can add is that i am using a spinner.

Here is the array for the spinner choices

```
    String[] periods= {"This month","Two Months","Three Months","Six Months","Year","All"};

 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.payments);            

         ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,periods);
         dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);  

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

So in the on itemselected listener i added.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(periods[pos]=="This month")
        {
            // get data within one month
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
             Date myStartDate =c1.getTime();
            Date myendDate = c.getTime();
            String s = fm.format(myStartDate);
            String e = fm.format(myendDate);
            Log.e("sdate", s);
            Log.e("edate", e);
            rentalpayments= new RentalPaymentsAdapter(this,s,e);
            list.setAdapter(rentalpayments);

        }else if(periods[pos]=="Two Months")
        {
            // get data within one month
                        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
                         Date myStartDate =c1.getTime();
                        Date myendDate = c.getTime();
                        String s = fm.format(myStartDate);
                        String e = fm.format(myendDate);
                        Log.e("sdate", s);
                        Log.e("edate", e);
                        rentalpayments= new RentalPaymentsAdapter(this,s,e);
                        list.setAdapter(rentalpayments);

        }else if(periods[pos]=="Three Months")
        {
            // get data within one month
                        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-2);
                         Date myStartDate =c1.getTime();
                        Date myendDate = c.getTime();
                        String s = fm.format(myStartDate);
                        String e = fm.format(myendDate);
                        Log.e("sdate", s);
                        Log.e("edate", e);
                        rentalpayments= new RentalPaymentsAdapter(this,s,e);
                        list.setAdapter(rentalpayments);

        }

        else if(periods[pos]=="Six Months")
        {
            // get data within one month
                        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH,-5);
                         Date myStartDate =c1.getTime();
                        Date myendDate = c.getTime();
                        String s = fm.format(myStartDate);
                        String e = fm.format(myendDate);
                        Log.e("sdate", s);
                        Log.e("edate", e);
                        rentalpayments= new RentalPaymentsAdapter(this,s,e);
                        list.setAdapter(rentalpayments);

        }
        else if(periods[pos].equals("Year"))
        {
            // get data within one month
                        String test=periods[pos];
                        c1.add((GregorianCalendar.MONTH),-11);
                         Date myStartDate =c1.getTime();
                        Date myendDate = c.getTime();
                        String s = fm.format(myStartDate);
                        String e = fm.format(myendDate);
                        Log.e("test", test);
                        Log.e("sdate", s);
                        Log.e("edate", e);
                        rentalpayments= new RentalPaymentsAdapter(this,s,e);
                        list.setAdapter(rentalpayments);

        }
```

RentalPaymentAdapter is a base adapter which accepts start date and enddate as arguments

```
rentalpayments= new RentalPaymentsAdapter(this,s,e);
```

any clues?

Comment: What is `fm`? I bet it's a `SimpleDateFormat` and the format string is wrong. You probably used `mm` instead of `MM` for the months. Note that `mm` means minutes, not months.

Comment: I use SimpleDateFormat fm =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Works perfect !!

Comment: What i want is to get the correct date!...i am using it in a where clause. want to get correct results

Answer (score 0):

The code below works fine. As mentioned in the comment above. It seems like your format is not right.

```
DateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
// get date a year ago
        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -11);
        Date myStartDate = c1.getTime();
        Date myendDate = c.getTime();

        String s = fm.format(myStartDate);

        String e = fm.format(myendDate);

        System.out.println(String.format("sdate: %s", s));
    System.out.println(String.format("edate: %s", e));
```

Comment: Hello. My format correct. but i keep on getting weird results.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the code to be

```
c1.add((GregorianCalendar.MONTH), -11);
```

since the const may be different, while the method api is

```
public void add(int field,int amount)
```

Also use fix date for testing

```
//set date to last day of 2009
c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // 11 = december
c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
```

Comment: changed to c1.add((GregorianCalendar.MONTH),-11). get same errors!